# Is there a non-roaming path for VSCode extensions to store platform-dependent binary data?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

My Visual Studio Code extension relies upon a platform-dependent binary. Currently, users have to manually install it and configure the location in their settings; I would like to make things easier on the users by having the extension download and cache this binary.

From the [API documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#ExtensionContext), I identified 3 candidate locations for the cache:

- `context.globalStoragePath`: almost perfect, but on Windows it's under the "Roaming" profile (pending [migration to local profile](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/3884)), so hardly suitable to a ~30MB platform-dependent binary
- `context.storagePath`: a workspace-specific version of the above (also in the "Roaming" profile)
- `context.extensionPath`: not persisted between extension updates

Other options I am considering:

- A sibling directory of `context.extensionPath`, e.g `${context.extensionPath}/../my-extension-dependencies` - which looks ugly, and could collide with other extensions
- A sibling directory of the `.vscode` directory, e.g `${HOME}/.my-extension/dependencies` - and here, the trick would be to reliably find a user-writable directory

Comment: "so hardly suitable to a ~30MB platform-dependent binary" - Tbh, 30 MB is a joke. After a scan with TreeSize, it looks like my Roaming directory has 6 GB in total, 1 GB from VSCode extensions. Both the Java and C++ extensions often store more than 30 MB _per workspace_... https://i.imgur.com/9qqR5gl.png